# How to iterate over a vector and compare the elements without using a clone to prevent a borrow error

Tags: rust

This is my working code where `things` is a `Vec<[u8 ; 32]>`

```
let t_copy = tx.things.clone();

for (index, value) in tx.things.into_iter().enumerate() {
    if tx.id == value {
        return Err(CustomError);
    }
    if t_copy[index].max(t_copy[index+1]) == t_copy[index]  {
        return Err(CustomError);
    }

}
```

I use `into_iter` rather than `iter` as I compare the values here:  `tx.id == tx_parent`

The above works but only because I clone the vector first which doesn't seem ideal to me. Is there a better way to achieve my goal here? Without the clone.

The purpose of the above code is to check the elements are in a certain order.

Comment: Hi there! Could you please provide a [MCVE]? This makes it easier to answer this question. Shouldn't be very hard to create the minimal example here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter), not [`into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), the former returns iterator that iterates over existing vector by borrowing it, the latter consumes data - takes ownership of the object, and directly turns it into iterator, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Sahsahe Thanks but then the problem I have is value is a reference (&[u8; 32]) and tx.id is not ([u8; 32]). If I write &tx.id == value will Rust automatically check the values?

Comment: When you're matching references, then you should use `&value`, when you want to dereference something, you should dereference it using `*`, it's not clear what your problem is, since you haven't shown us what tx is so I cannot answer your question, but for example, to match values to be plain `[u8; 32]`, you'd iterate over it like this: `for (index, &value) in things.iter().enumerate() { ... }` This is known as reference patterns: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns

Comment: @JamesSmith I would write `tx.id == *value` for the condition instead, which works for non-`Copy` types. (The `==` operator takes its arguments by reference implicitly, so `*value` in this context does not move out of `value`.)